# "glyphicon glyphicon-search" button is not attached to text field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask

I have in the *navbar-right* a search field with a button. However, the button is below the search field.
How is it possible to attach the button to the search field?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('home')}}">TEST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

        <li class="active"><a href="{{url_for('home')}}">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role="search">
    <form class="navbar-form" method="get" action="{{ url_for('search')}}" role="form">
      <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="snpid" placeholder="e.g. Hello">
      <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></span></button>
    </div>
      </div>
    </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `form-inline` class to your `input` parent div

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f2y4qe45/)**

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="snpid" placeholder="e.g. Hello">
  <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></span></button>
</div>
```

**OR:** Remove the extra parent `div.input-group` and you could also add `navbar-right` class to your `form` to position the form on the right.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ox4bsn45/)**

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get" action="{{ url_for('search')}}" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="snpid" placeholder="e.g. Hello">
        <button class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```